# Whats the equivalent of jQuery "eq()" in Mootools?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am new to Mootools and have been using jQuery for a while.  What I am trying to do is convert some jQuery into mootools.

I have the following written in jQuery :

```
var title = $('a:eq(2)').attr('title');
```

how would you write the equivalent in mootools?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the expected behavior of this `eq` construct in jQuery…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the double dollar function, which returns an array of elements matching the element type you supply  -

```
var title = $$('a')[2].title;
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wWbmC/

**Further Info**

http://mootools.net/blog/2010/03/19/a-better-way-to-use-elements/
http://solutoire.com/2007/09/20/understanding-mootools-selectors-e-and-es/

Comment: this will/can probably be more performant in older browsers that lack document.QSA, though use `.get("title")` and not the property directly as @oskar krawczyk suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Mootools docs have the answer, use the [`:index()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Slick/Slick#Slick%3aindex) selector:

```
$$('a:index(2)');       // Gets the third <a> tag.
```

To retrieve the title attribute use [getProperty](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetProperty):

```
var title = $('el').getProperty('title');
```

NB. This applies to MooTools Core v1.4.1

Comment: To get the title attribute would it be $$('a:index(2)').getAttribute('title');  ????

Comment: @ChillWebDesigns: almost, [`getProperty('title')`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getProperty)

Comment: `.get('title')` will suffice.

Comment: actually, this is not the same. `$$` (or `document.getElements` or `Slick.search`) returns a HTML collection, in this case - with 1 element. the jquery one returns a single element. to make it more performant, use `document.getElement("a:index(2)").get("title");` or even someotherNode.getElement (or Slick.find), no need to traverse all links in the DOM if possible.

Comment: doesn't work when combined with class selector, eg, `$$('.myclass:index(0)')` returns an empty array